# Facebook started sharing without being selected android studio

Tags: java, android, facebook, share

It does not allow me to select another social network like twitter when launching Intent.ACTION_SEND initiates the method of sharing of facebook.

My problem could be in the method when selecting in the package to share in the social network.

**fragment**

```
public void shareIt(View view){
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(imagencompartir);
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent,0);
    for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
        String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
       targetedShareIntent.setClassName(app.activityInfo.packageName, app.activityInfo.name); // add
        if(packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana") ){
        //    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setLinkShare();
           // targetedShareIntent.putExtra(this, MyIntentService.class);
           // targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, titulo.getText().toString());
            setLinkShare();
        } else
        if(packageName.equals("com.twitter.android")){
            targetedShareIntent.setType("application/twitter");
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, titulo.getText().toString().trim() );
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        } else {
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, titulo.getText().toString());
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, titulo.getText().toString());
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, comentariocompartir.getText().toString().trim());
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        }
        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
    }
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), getActivity().getString(R.string.compartir_con));

    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, RESULT_SHARE);

}
```

**Share method on Facebook**

```
public void setLinkShare() {
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()

        .setContentTitle(titulo.getText().toString().trim())
        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("https://scontent-sin6-1.xx.fbcdn.net/t31.0-8/13403381_247495578953089_8113745370016563192_o.png"))
        .setContentDescription(comentariocompartir.getText().toString().trim())
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"))
        .setShareHashtag(new ShareHashtag.Builder()
                .setHashtag("#app"+" "+ "#facebook")

                .build())
        .setQuote(titulo.getText().toString().trim())
        .build();

shareDialog.show(content, ShareDialog.Mode.NATIVE);
 }
```